# Defining VSCode's python interpreter in a monorepo using poetry's in-project virtualenvs

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a folder I open in VSCode that is a monorepo. One of the folders inside it is a python service.

This python service uses poetry with `in-project` virtualenvs configured. This means that I want my interpreter path to be `./python-service/.venv`.

Unfortunately, VSCode does not automatically detect the appropriate interpreter when a file inside that folder is opened (most likely because I'm opening the entire monorepo, not the specific service folder).

I know I can manually set an interpreter, but I would prefer if anyone else opening the folder doesn't also have to manually define the interpreter location.

It seems VSCode's `settings.json` file does support `python.venvPath` and `python.venvFolders` but this is only be configurable for a user's settings, not a workspace's settings.

What is the best way to tell VSCode which interpreter to pick?

Comment: [A similar feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20644) in github.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the article, setting the default interpreter can only be set in user `settings.json`, which is for global settings.

I think it is better to use debug and specify python interpreter in the `launch.json` file by using '[python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_python)':

You can add the full path that points to the Python interpreter to be used for debugging.

Comment: This technically works, but I struggle with it for two reasons. 1) It requires people to know to open vscode with the debug flag 2) I have to set one interpreter for the entire monorepo, rather than the specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

The VS Code extension [poetry-monorepo](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ameenahsanma.poetry-monorepo) does exactly this for poetry repos/monorepos. It takes the interpreter from the directory containing `pyproject.toml`.